Webview2 not navigating to URL after app installed
I have a Winforms C# VS2022 project targeting x64 using .Net 4.7.2. In the project is a form containing a Webview2 control name webView21. The control is set to show a URL with the code below:
string url = Common.GetConfig(Common.sEnv, "txtExampleImages");
webView21.Source = new Uri(url);

Running the project within VS2022 the URL is shown as expected. However, if I create an installer placing the files below in the executable folder and run the installer on a different machine (Win 11), a blank screen is shown. How can make the installed version show the specified URL?


There is no Console.Log in C#. Console. If I supply the url in Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = url, UseShellExecute = true }); the url shows in the default browser.

The following code (modified from answer supplied by @Bluejay) resulted in the specified URL being shown
public ExampleImages2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string url = Common.GetConfig(Common.sEnv, "txtExampleImages");
        InitializeWebView(url);
        
    }
    public async void InitializeWebView(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            var env = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, @"C:\Temp");
            await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);
            webView21.Source = new Uri(url);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" Error in Web View " + e.Message, "Application");
        }
    }

